# Rviz not displaying robot

Tags: ros, rviz, turtlebot, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I got rviz up and running now after changing OGRE_RTT_MODE to FBO. PBuffer would not open and Copy would not show any additional displays (such as camera). Currently my turtlebot is not being displayed and my camera is not displaying an image. I am assuming that the rviz doesn't see the turtlebot at all.

WORKSTATION:~$ export OGRE_RTT_MODE=FBO
WORKSTATION:~$ rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [1337349753.123480585]: rviz revision number 1.6.7
[ INFO] [1337349753.123598014]: ogre_tools revision number 1.6.2
[ INFO] [1337349753.123621172]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1337349753.237644311]: Loading general config from [/home/taylorclonts/.rviz/config]
[ INFO] [1337349753.238379520]: Loading display config from [/home/taylorclonts/.rviz/display_config]
[ INFO] [1337349753.289484441]: RTT Preferred Mode is FBO.
[ INFO] [1337349753.565056481]: Texture for pass 0: creating with size 1 x 1
[ INFO] [1337349753.566004859]: Texture for pass 1: creating with size 1 x 1
[ INFO] [1337349766.431133355]: RTT Preferred Mode is FBO.
[ INFO] [1337349819.066680998]: RTT Preferred Mode is FBO.

Any ideas? Any additional info needed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34292/rviz-not-displaying-robot/) by [TaylorC](https://answers.ros.org/users/2399/taylorc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2012-05-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-05-18**:
Do other "constant" things display, e.g. when you add a Grid or Axes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is working now. I had to just keep restarting it until it did. It is currently showing images from the camera and pointclouds. Currently I just need to lower the amount of data it is collecting as it is experiencing some horrible lag. I know I saw some articles about this here so I am going to look around.

---

Originally posted by [TaylorC](https://answers.ros.org/users/2399/taylorc/) with karma: 148 on 2012-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0